# Load Testing specific parts of HTTP page

Tags: jquery, web-applications, load-testing

Is there a way to load test a webapp using the JQuery framework beyond visiting HTTP addresses? The app I need to test uses many iframes to display the different information, and I haven't been able to find a tester capable of interacting with those.

I have been trying to see if JMeter is capable of doing this and haven't made any progress, and I'm pretty sure that the Grinder was incapable as well from my understanding of the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Selenium webdriver that simulate a browser. Consider that it implements a virtual browser so the number of instances that you can run on a single machine is limited by its resources. You would need a higher number of injectors.

Comment: That is cool! While it definitely looks useful, unfortunately it doesn't seem to do what I need it to. I need something to test how the server behaves with a large load of users.

Comment: You could use the Selenium webdriver in a load test. The only problem is that the number of driver instances per machine is limited so you could be forced to use more injectors than using another approach. 
Else you should replicate every HTTP request for the tested page and check the iframe content. I mean that the iframe content is an independent HTTP request and you should check its response. 
The first approach is more flexible but more resource consuming. 
For the second you must work a little more and it's not flexible but it's more resource effective